# Calling SQL Server database from Unix

Tags: sql-server, unix

With oracle currently there is a way to call a database through a command prompt using sqlplus. I'm wanting to know if there is a way to call a SQL Server server the same way so that I can have a shell script do it for me. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.freetds.org/

"FreeTDS is a set of libraries for Unix and Linux that allows your programs to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases. "

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/usefreetds.htm

> fisql
>
> A complete replacement of the isql utility programs distributed by Sybase and Microsoft. > Like them, fisql uses the command "go" on a line by itself as a separator between batches.